# Filtering lines using fscanf

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file of the form

```
A number,number
A number,number
[space] B number,number
etc
```

where I want to read only the lines that do start with a space (ie, in the example above, the last line only). I wrote this loop:

```
while ((g = fscanf(fp," %c %x,%d\n",&a,&b,&c) != EOF){
        printf("%c %x,%d\n",a,b,c);
    }
```

but despite the space I put at the beginning of the string, it still outputs all the lines. I know I can filter them inside the loop, but is it possible to specify it in the fscanf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP: it possible to specify it in the `fscanf`?
A: Yes, but its ugly.  Use the best tool for the job.

Use `fgets()`, then scan with `sscanf()`.

```
char buf[100];
char a;
unsigned b;
int c;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {
  // Thank-you @Chris Dodd
  if ((buf[0] == ' ') && (sscanf(buf, " %c%x,%d", &a,&b,&c) == 3)) {
    printf("%c %x,%d\n",a,b,c);
  }
}
```

Comment: `sscanf` needs `buf` as its first argument (the string to scan from).  As is, it should give you nasty compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to use ***getc*** and check for space , if space is found call ***ungetc*** and read the line using ***fgets*** else read the line and skip it